# Ways to STOP accepting Paypal Credit Debit cards

Tags: paypal

I sell digital goods that get send automatically when a transaction is complete and am using Paypal express, when a customer checks out to the Paypal page they have 2 choices:

1. login and pay with Paypal
2. Create a Paypal account and pay with card (I get so many chargebacks from this as anyone with a stolen card can create an account there and then! they don't have to wait 4 days to be verified!)

I've come up with a few ways to stop a transaction, does anyone know if these can be done?

1. If customer pays with card, the redirect code sends them somewhere else (error page) so that my code in the store doesn't see a complete transaction.
2. Is there a way to see if a transaction was made using a card, I think maybe on paypal pro, but will that info show up on my store, eg: IPN or would I have to log in to paypal to see it?
3. Is there an API out there that can see if a card was used and give my store the details, I would then have code like this:  if payment type card then don't send digital goods, if payment type paypal then send digital goods.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Why would you not want to take payments from cards/bank 95% of Paypal transactions are not with balance already on the account.

Comment: Chargebacks are the unfortunate part of digital distribution, I have been stung with it, I would suggest you send something physical to go with your digital item. or if your item is a PDF try putting signed DRM into your PDF so you can revoke the license if the user does a chargeback

Comment: Thank you for your reply but my whole selling is aimed at paypal users,  I put a higher price on my item because no one else sells it with paypal, anyone can buy my item with a credit/debit card and not pay the extra i charge, What I sell you can't pay for with paypal unless you buy it from me, so I don't want cards because who ever uses a card is stolen, hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would integrate [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/) into your system. It's free, doesn't offer credit cards and you have more control over the process.

If you want to offer cards, use Payments Pro and couple it with [Fraud Management Filters](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/fmf/integration-guide/FMFIntro/), which would afford you considerably more control over what cards you accept and decline.

In both cases you don't need to wait for an IPN. The API call itself will directly return the response you need.